# ESLint "Parsing error: Unexpected token : eslint" in React Typescript "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, typescript-eslint

In code such as:

```
const DPCOneJobScreenContainer = (props: IDpcOneJobScreenProps) => {
```

Eslint erros on the ":" no matter what the type is.

My Package.json

```
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
```

My .eslintrc.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
         "es6": true
        //"es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "standard"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

How can I ignore this in the "rules" ?

Thank you

Comment: you can't ignore this. eslint is literally failing to parse the entire file.

Comment: So what  Should I do? start from scratch?

Comment: nope; i had this issue before but i dont remember how to fix it